# Check if attribute errors is empty or not in a complex nesting of hashes and arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, nested

Let's say I have **a product that has many samples and each sample has many references**. 
At some point in the code I get a ruby hash (representing a product with nested attributes: samples > references) like this :

```
{
 name : '',
 category: 'toy',
 shop_id: '2',
 errors: {
   name: 'Cannot be empty'
 },
 samples_attributes: [
   {
     name: 'Big', 
     errors: {},
     references_attributes: [
       {
          quantity: 2, 
          price: nil, 
          errors: {price: 'cannot be nil'}
        }
      ]
   }, 
   {
     name: '12', 
     errors: {name: 'cannot be numerical'},
     references_attributes: [
       {
          quantity: -2, 
          price: 12, 
          errors: {quantity: 'cannot be negative'}
       }
      ]
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

I would like to find a clean way / trick to know if each of the items got the :errors attribute empty or not. It could return true or false in a method #nested_resources_got_errors?

For sure I could do that nesting `.each` methods but it is dirty:

```
def the_nested_resource_tree_has_errors?(product)
  !product[:errors].any? &&
  product[:samples_attributes].each do |sample|
    !sample[:errors].any? &&                                      
    sample[:references_attributes].each do |reference|
      !reference[:errors].any?
    end
  end
end
```

The code has to be **plain ruby**.

Comment: What do you mean by "Plain Ruby"? You're using Ruby on Rails features like `blank?`.

Comment: Did you mean to put `references_attributes` inside the `samples_attributes` array?

Comment: Thank you for noticing these points. I corrected the nesting. Also I replaced `blank?` by `!any?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make this into a generic recursive check. Using `any?` makes this more efficient, it will stop as soon as it finds an error.

```
def errors?(hash)
  # Does it have errors?
  return true if hash[:errors].present?

  # Iterate through each value until an error is found.
  return hash.any? do |_, value|
    case
    # Hash values are recursively checked.
    when value.is_a?(Hash)
      errors?(value)
    # Iterate through each element of an enumerable value.
    when value.is_a?(Enumerable)
      value.any? { |v| errors?(v) }
    end
  end
end
```

---

But this, and many other things, would be easier if these were objects. Set up some models. Each only needs to deal with itself and its immediate objects.

```
# A module for the error attribute and detecting errors.
module HasErrors
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :errors
  end

  def errors?
    errors.present?
  end
end

class Product
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include HasErrors
  attr_accessor :name, :category, :shop_id, :samples

  # check itself, then check its samples
  def errors?
    super || samples.any? { |sample| sample.errors? }
  end
end

class Sample
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include HasErrors
  attr_accessor :name, :references

  # check itself, then check its references
  def errors?
    super || references.any? { |ref| ref.errors? }
  end
end

class Reference
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include HasErrors
  attr_accessor :quantity, :price
end
```

Then you can put the data into objects and call `product.errors?`.

```
product = Product.new(
  name: '',
  category: 'toy',
  shop_id: '2',
  errors: {
    #name: 'Cannot be empty'
  },
  samples: [
    Sample.new(
      name: 'Big', 
      errors: {},
      references: [
        Reference.new(
          quantity: 2, 
          price: nil, 
          errors: {
            price: 'cannot be nil'
          }
        )
      ]
    ), 
    Sample.new(
      name: '12', 
      errors: {
        name: 'cannot be numerical'
      },
      references: [
        Reference.new(
          quantity: -2, 
          price: 12, 
          errors: {
            quantity: 'cannot be negative'
          }
        )
      ]
    )
  ]
)

p product.errors?
```

---

If we have models, we can use [validation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/) and the errors are not necessary.

```
module ValidateList
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def validate_list(attribute)
      validates_each attribute do |record, attr, values|
        # Check if any element of the list is invalid.
        record.errors.add(attr, :invalid) if values.any?(&:invalid?)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Product
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include HasName
  include ValidateList

  attr_accessor :category, :shop_id, :samples

  validate_list :samples
end

class Sample
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include HasName
  include ValidateList

  attr_accessor :references

  validate_list :references
end

class Reference
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :quantity, :price

  validates :price, :quantity,
    presence: true,
    numericality: {
      greater_than_or_equal_to: 0
    }
end

p product.valid?
p product.errors.details
```

Using validations will allow these models to work well with other parts of Rails.

Comment: Very interesting response @Schwern. The fact is that in my company we decided to change the architecture of the code in order to split App | Domain | Infrastrusture. We will not be using rails anymore at least in the domain (that is what I mean by plain ruby). We'll only take advantages of ActiveRecord when arriving in the infra. So I have to play validations of all my business rules (in a given use case) before I send the data to the infra for persistence in the DB. I am new at coding so I am grateful for those new ruby tricks `#errors?(hash)`

Comment: @NicolasB. Note this is not ActiveRecord, it is ActiveModel which you [can obtain separately from the rest of Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel). Seems kinda silly to re-implement all that.